# My returnList[0] gets rewritten to @5'

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, strcpy

I am trying to return an array of strings and while I copy the strings something weird happens when it passes the 4th index. For example, when it loops through the first 3 times it is stored as "the" but then it sudden becomes rewritten but it writes the next index just fine[index 5]. Can you guys find anything wrong with it because I'm stumped.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hash.h"
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 200
#define TERMINATE "asdfghjkl"

int createTable(int numFiles, char** files, char** stopList)
{
  printf("stepped into create table\n");
  FILE* fp1;
  char oneWord[100];

  HashTable hash = InitializeTable(900000);
  int index = 2;

  while(numFiles >0) {
    fp1 = fopen(files[index++], "r");
    while(fscanf(fp1, "%s", oneWord)!=EOF){
      Insert(oneWord, hash, stopList);
    }
  numFiles--;
  }
  return 0;
} 

char** createStopList(char* stopL)
{
  FILE* fp1;
  fp1 = fopen(stopL, "r");
  char oneWord[100];
  int i = 0;  
  char* stopList[MAX];
  while(fscanf(fp1, "%s", oneWord)!=EOF){
    stopList[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(oneWord));
    strcpy(stopList[i++], oneWord);
  }
  stopList[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
  strcpy(stopList[i], TERMINATE);

  char** strings = stopList;
  char** returnList = malloc(sizeof(strings));
  i=0;
  while(strcmp(strings[i], TERMINATE)!=0){
    returnList[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(returnList[i], strings[i]);
    i++;
  }
  returnList[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
  strcpy(returnList[i], TERMINATE);
  return returnList;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("start of prg\n");
  char** stopList= createStopList(argv[1]);
  createTable(argc-2, argv, stopList);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see a bunch of possible buffer overflows in your code. For example, by having an entry in the stopL file that's longer than 99 chars.

Comment: Not to mention memory leaks

Comment: The error from what I get from gdb is occurring right after I malloc when it is done looping through. I also went ahead and increased the buff size and freed some of the memory I allocated but to no avail.

Comment: Hey guys, I went ahead and tried to use strdup instead of strcpy and it seems to have worked for now. I'm still working on freeing all of my allocated memory but thanks for the help. You guys are awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code causes a buffer overflow:

```
#define TERMINATE "asdfghjkl"
// ...
returnList[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
strcpy(returnList[i], TERMINATE);
```

The length of `TERMINATE` is `10`, but `sizeof(char*)` is probably less than `10`.

To fix it:

```
returnList[i] = malloc( sizeof TERMINATE );
strcpy(returnList[i], TERMINATE);
```

Your comments suggest you used `strdup` instead (that function is not in Standard C, but it is commonly provided).

This is also completely fubar'd:

```
char** strings = stopList;
char** returnList = malloc(sizeof(strings));
// ...
returnList[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

`sizeof(strings)` is the same as `sizeof(char **)`, which is probably `4` or `8`, but you go on to write past the end of this array, as soon as `i` gets to `1`! This is probably the cause of your symptoms.

I think perhaps you have a misconception about what `sizeof` does. It tells you how many bytes are used to store a variable (NOT how many bytes are at the location the variable is pointing to, if that variable is a pointer).

Presumably you meant:

```
returnList = malloc( (i+1) * sizeof *returnList );
```

which gives you enough pointers for indices `returnList[0]` through `returnList[i]`.

The code after that is badly designed, you have unnecessary code duplication. Change the `while` loop to `do...while`, then the last iteration will copy `TERMINATE` for you without you having to write extra code for it.

Earlier on in that same function, this line is poor:

```
while(fscanf(fp1, "%s", oneWord)!=EOF){
```

You should prevent the input overflowing. Also you never check whether `i` exceeds `MAX`. And could make another improvement. Instead of copying `TERMINATE` into stopList, just save `i`, and write `TERMINATE` on the end of `returnList`.

Finally you seem to be pointlessly storing and copying your array instead of just dynamically allocating it in the first place.  Oh, and your mallocs have warts.

Putting all of those changes together:

```
char **createStopList(char const *stopL)
{
    FILE* fp1;
    fp1 = fopen(stopL, "r");
    char oneWord[100];
    size_t i;
    char **stopList;

    if ( !fp1 )
        return NULL;

    stopList = malloc(MAX * sizeof *stopList);
    if ( !stopList )
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    for (i = 0; i < MAX - 1 && fscanf(fp1, "%99s", oneWord) == 1; ++i)
    {
        stopList[i] = malloc( strlen(oneWord) + 1); 
        if ( !stopList[i] )
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        strcpy(stopList[i], oneWord);
    }

    stopList[i] = malloc(sizeof TERMINATE);
    strcpy(returnList[i], TERMINATE);

// (optional) free entries you didn't use in the list
    stopList = realloc(stopList, (i+1) * sizeof *returnList);
    if ( !stopList )
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return stopList;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks man. Yeah, I'm still learning C and dealing with memory so your answer was really helpful. Thanks again